# Algorithm to compute a contour for a high dimensional function

Tags: algorithm

I posted this on another stack exchange thing, but actually think this might be a more relevant location...

I would like to efficiently estimate a curve C(F_bar} such that F(x,y,z,w,...)=F_bar = const, where F(.) is a function of many inputs.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm?

Comment: You can use a variation of the marching cubes algorithm to find the surface corresponding to F_bar.  The simple implementation requires you to choose the domain in advance and traverse the whole space incrementally. If the dimensionality his high, that takes a while. Marching cubes in this variant is most useful for finding many contours on one pass over the subdivided domain. For a single contour, you can "follow" the contour by searching only adjacent cuboids from an initial starting one that contains the surface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that a curve - or anything else very much - will be very helpful in large numbers of dimensions. A curve is 1-dimensional, and the obvious analogy to a contour in N dimensions is a surface, which in N dimensions will be an N-1 dimensional object. Furthermore, as the number of dimensions gets large things get complex and surprising. See for example the answers and references in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99171/why-is-euclidean-distance-not-a-good-metric-in-high-dimensions.

With that warning, two ideas spring to mind:

1) Fix all but two of the variables in f(x,y,w,z...). This leaves you with only two variables free, so you have a function of two variables, and you can do a perfectly ordinary contour plot for it.

2) Find the value of f(x,y,w,z...) at a large number of randomly chosen points. With any luck some will be above F_bar and some will be below it. Assuming that your function is continuous, if you pick a point where the value is above F_bar and a point where the value is below F_bar, then there is a point somewhere on the line between them where f() is equal to F_bar. If you pick three points, where one of them is on one side of F_bar and the other two are on the other side of F_bar then these three points describe a plane, and there is a contour running through that plane where f() is equal to F_bar.